# qemu-system-arm -redir invalid option

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arm, emulation, qemu

Trying to follow https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/ to set up the lab. The following command is giving an error

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel '/root/Documents/Raspbian qemu/qemu-rpi-kernel-master/kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie' -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda '/root/Documents/Raspbian qemu/2017-04-10-raspbian-jessie.img' -redir tcp:5022::22 -no-reboot

qemu-system-arm: -redir: invalid option
```

Answer (score 24):

You're using a newer QEMU version than the document author was. -redir was first deprecated and then removed altogether. https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/RemovedFeatures is where the project documents removed options and the replacement options you should use instead.

In this case I think "-redir tcp:5022::22" becomes "-nic user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22".

Comment: I found: -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22

Comment: The new syntax is even more of a PITA to remember… ☹ so, apparently: `-net user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:2222-:22 -net nic,model=e1000` (don’t omit the address, otherwise it listens on 0.0.0.0 and that may be… undesired)